# Call .prepend() on a div's id and class

Tags: jquery, class, html, prepend

How can I call prepend on a `div`'s `id` and `class`?  I was thinking I can do something like this:

```
$('#id .class').prepend('Text');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to select a single element with an id of `ID` Use a comma to separate the selectors:

```
$('#ID,.class').prepend('Text');
```

If you're trying to select a div with an id of `ID` *and* class of `class` then remove the space between the two:

```
$('#ID.class').prepend('Text');
```

Although this second method is rather redundant since IDs need to be unique to a single element in the document.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it isn't grabbing a div with the ID and Class, it is still just looking at class.  So every div with the same class is getting the prepend.  Weird huh?

Comment: Okay, so to correct your code Clive, it is just #ID.class with not comma.  I don't know why I didn't remember that.

Comment: @drummer392: Updated in the answer above, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @drummer392: You beat me to it :-)

Comment: It should work perfectly fine with the comma notation as well. What version of Jquery are you using?

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik: OP isn't trying to get multiple elements, just one with a particular class *and* ID. Even though it's redundant the second code in the answer above will do it

Comment: Ah, Clive got it.  I am using the latest version from Google API

Comment: @Clive, for my application it won't be redundant. I am wanting certain information to go to all the divs with a certain class, but I want more specific information to do to divs of a certain ID with that class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".class, #ID").prepend('Text');
```

Edit: While trying it I see a similar answer was posted and doesn't seem to work. It should work. The issue must lie somewhere else in your program logic.

Try comparing `$('.class')` with `$('#ID')` in Firebug